# Quantmod is not pulling Yahoo finance data for me anymore

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, quantmod

I have been using the same code for nearly two years which have reliably returned stock information for me. Couple of days ago I started to get the following error message: "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401."

Here is a reproducible example of the code I have been using:

```
# install.packages("quantmod") 
library(quantmod)

what_metrics1 <- yahooQF(c("P/E Ratio",
                           "Price/Book",
                           "Book Value", 
                           "Previous Close",
                           "52-week High",
                           "Change"))

Stocks<- c("BAC", "AAPL")
metrics1 <- getQuote(paste(Stocks, sep="", collapse=";"), what=what_metrics1)
```

I have tried to turn the computer on and off, ran the code on a different computer, but the error message persisted. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/382).

Comment: Thank you neilfws. The link you provided helped me out.